# Sort a d-sorted array

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, big-o, computer-science

Given an array [1,...,n], The array will be called **d-sorted**, if every key in the array is located in a distance not greater then a constant ***d*** from his location in the sorted array **A**

I need to write algorithms that get a d-sorted array with the length of n and sorts the array in the runtime of:

1. Θ(n) if **d** is a constant
2. Θ(n(log(log(n)))) if **d** is Θ(log(n))

My Attempts:
I wrote this following pseudo-code:

```
Sort_d_array(A[],d)
 min-heap-size <- d
 for i <- 1 to n 
    BUILD-MIN-HEAP(min-heap,heap-size)
      if min-heap not empty
        then EXTRACT-MIN <- A[i]
          if i+d<=n
            then heap-insert-min(min-heap,A[i+d])
```

But in terms of runtime, all I get is BigO(nlog(log(d)))

> **MY METHOD:** I initialized `i <- 1` and then I built a `min-heap` that contains all of the first d elements
>  as long as the `heap is not empty`, I used `EXTRACT-MIN` and put the element at i index in
> the array and if `i+d<=n`, then `A[i+d]` will be an element in the
> min-heap

Any help?

Comment: O(n log (log d)) is O(n) if d is constant, and O(n log log n) if d is O(log n)